# Why does boost::filesystem::path return a path instead of string

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I have this peace of code

```
string targetFile = string + boost::filesystem::path.filename()
```

the problem is that it considers `path.filename()` as path instead of the string that the documentation tells (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-template-basic_path)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using boost 1.36? Newer versions of Boost [document](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-filename) it to return a path:

```
path filename() const;
```

Comment: I have boost 1.6 , is that the probleme ?

Comment: @MekacherAnis It’s not a problem, the answer is simply telling you that you are looking at the wrong version of the documentation. Here’s the [correct documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-filename).

Comment: @MekacherAnis It is if you're coding based on the documentation of v1.36. But you don't really *have* to do that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph alright thank's , it was like a nightmare

Answer (score 0):

```
string targetFile = string + boost::filesystem::path.filename().string();
```

you can use like that.

Comment: what does the .string() do

Comment: @MekacherAnis I believe you had found the correct documentation in the mean time.